# Symfony 3/4 : delete a table row from a database through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, post

I am a little bit stuck on my Symfony code.

**Let me explain**,

I have a todo-list table in my database containing :

- **An ID** called : id
- A name field called : todo
- And 3 others fields that don't matter : *"completed", "created_at", "updated_at"*.

---

Before going further : **here is my codes**,

*The concerned Controller* :

```
  /**
 * @Route("/todos/delete/{id}", name="todo.delete", methods={"POST"})
 * @param Todo $todo
 * @param ObjectManager $manager
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function delete(Todo $todo, ObjectManager $manager, Request $request)
{
    $manager->remove($todo);
    $manager->flush();

    if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('todo.home', [
            'id' => $todo->getId()
        ]);
    }
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('The todo couldn\'t be deleted');
}
```

*The view* :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Todos{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<form action="{{ path('todo.create') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('todo-create') }}"/>
    <label for="todo">Todo</label>
    <input type="text" id="todo" name="todo" class="form-control input-group-lg" placeholder="Create a new todo">
</form><br>
{% for todo in todos %}
    {{ todo.todo }}
    <a href="{{ path('todo.update', {'id': todo.id}) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</a>
    <a href="{{ path('todo.delete', {'id': todo.id}) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm js-delete-todo" id="{{ todo.id }}">x</a>
    {% if todo.completed %}
        <a href="{{ path('todo.completed', {'id': todo.id}) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Completed !</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="{{ path('todo.completed', {'id': todo.id}) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Mark as completed</a>
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

*We focus on* :

```
<a href="{{ path('todo.delete', {'id': todo.id}) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm js-delete-todo" id="{{ todo.id }}">x</a>
```

*The JavaScript* :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.js-delete-todo').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    delTodo(url);

    function delTodo(url) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#id').remove();
        }).fail(function () {
            alert('Could not be deleted');
        });
     }
  });
});
```

**Actually**,

Everything seems to work : it does a **POST** ajax request, and delete the row in my table in my database.

The only issue is that I have to hit F5 to see it.

How can I make it work without reloading the page nor hitting the F5 hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your symfony code you should return JSON format like [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response).
Wrap your todo in container like this

```
{% for todo in todos %}
  <div id="todo-{{todo.id}}">
    // your todo staff here 
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Then change your javascript to

```
function delTodo(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url
    }).done(function (data) {
        var id = JSON.parse(data).id;
        $('#todo-' + id).remove();
    }).fail(function ()
        alert('Could not be deleted');
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
I used your example and customized it, and it's working great !